# Expand inline tags in custom Javadoc taglet

Tags: java, javadoc, custom-tag, taglet

I wrote a custom Javadoc taglet that adds a new `note` tag:

```
 ...
 public boolean isInlineTag() { return false; }

  public String toString(Tag tag) {
      return "<pre class='note'>" + tag.text() + "</pre>";
   }
```

It works so far, but inline tags are not expanded. Here is an example comment:

```
/**
 * @note Test note with {@link Someclass} // @link tag is NOT expanded
 * @param name - here the {@link Someclass} works // works for standard 'param' tag
 */
```

The `{@link}` inline tag is not expanded. However, it works just fine for the built-in `param` javadoc tag.

Is there a way to expand nested inline tags in a custom Javadoc taglet?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Taglet overview](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/javadoc/taglet/overview.html) says:

> Taglets can be written as either block tags, such as @todo, or inline tags, such as {@underline}. Block taglets do not currently support inline tags in their text.

In fact, the taglet API is a bit too minimal, as it supports only the `toString()` method.

You could inside this method retrieve the subtags of the parameter `tag`  (with `.inlineTags()`), but then you would have to format them yourself, since you don't have access to the normal machinery of the standard doclet from your taglet.

So, looks like you are out of luck here, if you don't want to reimplement (or copy) parts of the standard doclet in your own taglet. (But then, you could the same directly extend the standard doclet instead of patching it with taglets.)

Answer (score 1):

Here's three possible ideas, none of which I really like:

1. Instead of defining your own `Taglet`, use the `-tag` option to the `javadoc` command to support `@note`.  Of course, this won't let you define your own custom formatting.
2. You could use `tag.holder().setRawCommentText(String)`.  My experience playing with this is that this lets you add tags, but doesn't let you rewrite a tag.  So you can't do a string replacement on `tag.holder().getRawCommentText()` and then have the standard doclet render the inline tags properly, but you could probably have your `Taglet.toString(Tag[])` method generate the html, including the raw form of the inline tags, and then append to the raw comment text "`@renderedNote` *markedUp Tag.text()*" where `@renderedNote` is another tag, defined using `-tag`.  Your `Taglet.toString(Tag[])` should then return an empty string.  However, not only is this ugly, I don't know if this relies on undocumented behavior and so I don't know how robust or future proof this idea is.
3. You could have your `Taglet` also implement `com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.taglets.Taglet`.  This seems to be how the standard taglets are defined.  The two methods you then have to implement are `TagletOutput getTagletOutput(Tag tag, TagletWriter writer)` and `TagletOutput getTagletOutput(Doc doc, TagletWriter writer)`.  I think the latter can just `throw IllegalArgumentException()`.  If you also keep the `Map` provided when your `Taglet` was registered, then you may be able to render several of the inline tags that you encounter by looking up the tag name in that `Map` to get its implementing `com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.taglets.Taglet` and delegating to its `getTagletOutput` method.  However, it looks like, for example, `@link` tags are not registered in that map; for those, it's possible (but I haven't checked) that because `@link` tags are supposedly provided as `SeeTag` you may be able to use the map from `@see` instead, or you could cast the `TagletWriter` to `TagletWriterImpl` and then use `TagletWriterImpl.seeTagOutput(Doc, SeeTag[])`.  For `Text` tags, you can generate `TagletOutput` instances via `new TagletOutputImpl(String)`.  Finally all the `TagletOutput` instances that you get this way can be combined into a single `TagletOutput` to be returned using `TagletOutput.append(TagletOutput)`.